# May open sentences be eliminated?

Tags: lo.logic

Saul Kripke famously invoked a free logic to avoid validating the Barcan Formula and its converse. In that context he adduced a *generality interpretation* of free variables. The converse of the Barcan formula is derivable in standard classical modal logic by noticing that $\Box(\forall x\alpha(x)\rightarrow\alpha(y))$ and so by distibution get $\Box\forall x\alpha(x)\rightarrow\Box\alpha(y)$ and so by generalization and a quantifier rule get $\Box\forall x\alpha(x)\rightarrow\forall y\Box\alpha(y)$. But this proof procedure is blocked by Kripke's approach as $\forall x\alpha(x)\rightarrow\alpha(y)$ is then not valid whereas $\forall y(\forall x\alpha(x)\rightarrow\alpha(y))$ is.

May one presuppose an axiomatic theory along such lines as this for theories with referring terms, such as Peano arithmetics or set theory with set terms, and avoid open sentences altogether (in such a theory for PA we would e.g. be allowed to instantiate with number terms as $SSS0$ but not with variables)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know about modal logic, but for theories like PA and ZFC which use ordinary predicate calculus the answer is yes. You can formulate any first order predicate calculus only in terms of closed sentences. For intuitionistic logic this merely involves dropping the generalization rule from a Hilbert-style system and replacing modus ponens with: from $\overline{A}$ and $\overline{A \to B}$, infer $\overline{B}$, where $\overline{A}$ is any universal closure of $A$. To get classical logic, just include as axioms universal closures of all instances of the law of excluded middle. See Chapter 2, Section 4.4 of *Constructivism in Mathematics* vol. 1 by Troelstra and van Dalen.

Comment: One would need a rule or schema to allow instantiation with specific numerals in PA, right? Would such a system for set theory need set abstracts to refer to specific sets?

Comment: Look at the reference I gave. $(\forall x)A(x) \to A(t)$, with $t$ free for $x$ in $A$, is one of the Hilbert axiom schemes. No, you don't need set abstracts, this works for any first order predicate calculus with only the modifications I stated.

Comment: I see that one needs no set abstracts as long as one has extensionality. In PA extensionality also reigns - as on can see if one takes the numbers to be finite von Neumann ordinals - so one needs no numerals. However, if one's set theory is not extensional one would better use set abstrats. I

Comment: I'm not sure why you think that, but again, look at the book by Troelstra and van Dalen. What I am telling you is a general fact of logic. Extensionality is only meaningful in set-theoretic settings and doesn't come into it.

Comment: Set abstracts can be eliminated from LAST precisely because of extensionality, as then $\{x|Fx\}$ is the y s.t. $\forall x(x\in y\leftrightarrow Fx)$.

To my recollection, by an observation of Tarski, one may do something as you suggest in your answer by keeping modus ponens as the only inference rule and have the generalisations of $\forall x(Fx\rightarrow Gx)\rightarrow(\forall xFx\rightarrow\forall x Gx)$ as axiom schemas.

I will take a look at your reference when I can. Greetings from Moscow on the way to the Mints-event in Saint Petersburg.

Comment: Naslazhdaites Peterburg. Udacha!

Comment: Благодарности из Санкт-Петербурга!